# Numbers on Google Map API markers?

Tags: php, mysql, html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i'm using GoogleMap API in my project where the position of a particular vehicle is rendered by using data in the DB, i have already implemented this, MY question is if its possible to get numbers on the Markers,e.x Vehicle A has been in 100 places from 1 to 2 of Decembre, i would like having numbers starting from 1 to 100 kinda showing its path,This is the create marker function of my Google API:

```
    function createMarker(point, IMEI, Velocity, Ora, Data) {   
      var marker = new GMarker(point, iconBlue); 
      var html = "<b>" + "Ora: " + "</b>" + Ora + "<br/>" + "<b>" + "Data: " + "</b>"+ Data + "<br/>" + "<b>" + "Velocità: " + "</b>" + Velocity + " km/h" ; 
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html); });
      return marker;
     }
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to generate markers for those values.  You could do this easily with a php script that would write numbers over your base marker.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [article](http://www.googlemapsbook.com/2007/01/22/extending-gmarker/) on how to extend marker to add a label. It's pretty old though, so I'm not sure if it works with current version of GMaps.